# Windows 7 resolution missing

Tags: windows-7, display

I brought home a new Samsung Syncmaster b2030. Plugged in. But cannot find 1600x900 resolution. Cleared "Hide modes that this monitor cannot display" and clicked apply. But still not solved. I also tried "List All Modes". 1600x900 is not there. Anything I am missing?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your computer may not be able to drive a monitor at that high of a resolution.  Post some info about your graphics card.

Answer (score 0):

You don't even have any drivers installed.  <strike>Go download [the correct video drivers for your chipset from the Intel site](http://downloadcenter.intel.com/Detail_Desc.aspx?ProdId=2032&DwnldID=12536) (you have an integrated GPU).</strike>

The "vga" driver you are using is meant for use only during install when the correct driver isn't known yet, and for troubleshooting if the correct driver becomes corrupt or has some other problem.  It only supports a few very basic very standard resolutions.

Your video chipset isn't supported on Win7, and it's integrated so you can't upgrade to newer graphics (this is a laptop, correct?).  If you need high resolution and the frame rate isn't important, you could try a USB video adapter.  But that old computer may not even have USB 2.0, in which case you really have no options.

Comment: No Intel drivers available for W7 and that graphics controller...http://downloadcenter.intel.com/Detail_Desc.aspx?agr=Y&DwnldID=18576&keyword=82915&lang=eng

Comment: @Moab: I don't know why I was thinking an XP system when the Title clearly says Win7.  Maybe because 915 chipsets stopped being sold long before Vista was released.

Answer (score 0):

There are no Intel drivers for that graphics controller (82915G/GL)

[Source](http://downloadcenter.intel.com/Detail_Desc.aspx?agr=Y&DwnldID=18576&keyword=82915&lang=eng)

You will need to install a PCI or AGP graphics card if it is a Desktop PC, otherwise you are out of luck on a notebook.

Comment: Intel integrated graphics is mostly used in laptops, I'd be surprised if he has a system with any sort of expansion slot.

Comment: I made the assumption since they were using an external monitor, in which case I could be wrong.